# Can't setup virtual host (apache/bind/webmin) to work with domain (ubuntu 10.04 LAMP)

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up a fresh Ubuntu 10.04 as my web server but I'm having no joy at all - I can't access the domain via a browser (it times out) and I get no ping response except when I ping from the server itself. I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to this aspect of server config so please bear with me.

I installed 10.04 LTS then apache, mysql and php (all appear to be working fine). I've also installed Webmin and Virtualmin. I seem to be able to create the virtual hosts without any problem, and I can access the server using its IP and its name (servername.kimsufi.com).  Bind9 came installed with the default distro, so I've not made any changes to it except those made automatically by Virtualmin/Webmin.

I'm sure it's something simple but I've been reading for ages and tweaking, to no avail.

Here's a pastebin of my bind config files: http://pastebin.com/RAFyYG5m

The domain in question (domain.net) has its nameservers set to my server (servername.kimsufi.com) and the host's secondary nameserver (ns.kimsufi.com).

Here's the hosts file for the domain:

```
root@server:/var/lib/bind# cat domain.net.hosts
$ttl 38400
@       IN      SOA     server.kimsufi.com. root.server.kimsufi.com. (
                        1327162497
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
@       IN      NS      server.kimsufi.com.
@       IN      NS      ns.kimsufi.com.
domain.net.        IN      A       1.2.3.4
www.domain.net.    IN      A       1.2.3.4
ftp.domain.net.    IN      A       1.2.3.4
m.domain.net.      IN      A       1.2.3.4
localhost.domain.net.      IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

(Obviously the server's real IP isn't 1.2.3.4...)

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: > I seem to be able to create the virtual hosts without any problem, and I can access the server using its IP and its name (servername.kimsufi.com). So then what exactly are you having trouble doing? ("No joy" = ?)

Comment: I can't access the domain from a browser - it doesn't ping from any machine except the server itself, and browser requests just time out (both with and without the www).

Comment: Without knowing the particulars of the network, in general it might help to do nslookup or dig from inside and outside the network, to find where the resolution is failing.  Also, to clarify troubleshooting, are ICMP packets blocked at the gateway? If so, disregard ping results.

Comment: Does the name resolve correctly?  Does it have a firewall in front of it?  Is the browser you're on able to connect to its public address, or does it need to use a private address instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the listen-on IP in /etc/bind/named.conf.options was set to 127.0.0.1 instead of the server's public IP. I changed that, restarted bind, and everything is working as expected now :)

Confusing that it should be configured only to listen to itself on installation (or that the file doesn't include a useful comment to explain what needs to be changed to expose bind to the outside world).